# Celery can't find Redis in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, redis, celery

I am running Celery in Kubernetes pod. It can't find the server:

> ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to redis://:**@redis-master:6379/1: Error -3 connecting to redis-master:6379. Lookup timed out..
> Trying again in 4.00 seconds... (1/100)

If I connect to the very same pod via "kubectl exec -it" and run the command, I succeed:

> redis-cli -u redis://:@redis-master:6379/1 keys '*'
>
> (empty list or set)

How can I troubleshoot this problem?

---

**UPDATE 1**:
Problem obviously in DNS:

If I set host to domain name:

```
export REDIS_HOST=redis-master.dev.svc.cluster.local
celery worker --app src
TIMEOUT
```

If I set host to domain name:

```
export REDIS_HOST=10.0.13.13
celery worker --app src
OK
```

Meanwhile:

```
# dig redis-master.dev.svc.cluster.local
; <<>> DiG 9.11.5-P4-5.1+deb10u1-Debian <<>> redis-master.dev.svc.cluster.local
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; WARNING: .local is reserved for Multicast DNS

;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 49071
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;redis-master.dev.svc.cluster.local. IN A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
redis-master.dev.svc.cluster.local. 30 IN A 10.0.13.13

;; SERVER: 10.0.0.10#53(10.0.0.10)
```

Thus, the problem is narrowed down to:
Why Celery doesn't use DNS?

---

**UPDATE 2**:
Problem in Python library [dnspython](https://pypi.org/project/dnspython/#history).
Version 2.0.0 - bug in resolving
Version 1.16.0 - works like a charm

---

**SOLUTION**

pip install dnspython==1.16.0

Comment: edit the question to add all the deployment yamls. redis pods running?

Comment: Hey @Michael A, have you tried using Redis svc IP instead of hostname? have you checked the environment vars you're passing to Celery matching redis-master?

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu "redis pods running?" - As I mentioned in question it is not just running but also successfully responds if I reach it from within the very same pod. This is why I didn't publish YAMLs - it works manually with these YAMLs.

Comment: @marianogg9 It is written in Celery output error: proper server name. No need to check if Celery got proper address if it prints proper address :-)

Answer (score 4):

Answering myself:

This is a dnspython bug.
Solution:

```
pip install dnspython==1.16.0
```